# Host redirection not working boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have installed docker(docker 1.6) via boot2docker vm in OSX environment.

In my host machine I have redirected a host entry (in /etc/hosts). Following is my host file entry

```
dockerreigstry.score.local  10.2.2.132
```

This host redirection not available for boot2docker. If I ssh to boot2docker and execute

```
boot2docker ssh
ping dockerreigstry.score.local
```

it always goes to original ip address(not to 10.2.2.132).

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493920/docker-containers-not-using-host-dns-in-boot2docker?

Comment: Ya, it also contains the solution.. Following is the solution for it (http://serverfault.com/questions/453185/vagrant-virtualbox-dns-10-0-2-3-not-working/453260#453260)