# How to change "default" docker-machine's dns settings

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I know how to create a new docker-machine with dns settings

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 my_machine
```

But there is already a "default" virtualmachine so is there a way to change its dns?

I read online ways to do this with boot2docker, but that tool is deprecated and docker-machine has replaced it. Unfortunately, it's so new that I haven't found much online about this.

Comment: My workaround is to remove the original "default" host and create a new one (same name) with the dns settings I need

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Go to `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json` and add your own DNS server into `HostOptions/EngineOptions/Dns` and restart docker machine.

```js
{  
   "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": ["192.168.99.1","8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"], <-- set it here
            "GraphDir": ""
        }
}
```

Edit:

The Dns setting in `config.json` seems to be ignored in the new version of docker-machine. The only thing that seems to work is to add line (edit this to match your needs)

```
"${DOCKER_MACHINE}" ssh "${VM}" "sudo sed -i.bkp '/--label provider=virtualbox/a --dns 8.8.8.8\\\n--dns 8.8.4.4' /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"
```

after

```
yes | "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" regenerate-certs "${VM}"
```

in script `start.sh`, which is run every time Docker Quickstart Terminal is started.

Then shut down the machine (if it's running) and open a new instance of the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Comment: I saw the config and thought this might be an option. But it wasn't referenced anywhere so I wasn't sure if this was the standard method encouraged by Docker...?

Comment: it might help others if you showed the contents of this config.json and a before/after snapshot of the settings for those who aren't familiar. I can accept this answer after that if a better one doesn't come up

Comment: docker-machine is quite under documented. so config.json format is not publicly documented yet

Comment: In my `config.json` the "Dns" value was `null`. Replacing it with a list containing just the 8.8.x.x servers worked for me. I'm guessing the 192.168.99.1 is only needed if you have custom DNS entries set up locally.

Comment: In my `config.json` the "Dns" value is also `null`, however at the runtime the machine /etc/resolv.conf has `192.168.1.1` set for name server.  I am trying to understand where this IP came from.  Note that this IP does not work for me.  More strange thing is that, the docker-machine and the containers used to able to reach out the outside world, i.e. the DNS used to work, but I don't know what the value was when it was working.

Comment: FYI -- You can also `docker-machine provision name` to apply any config changes without needing to restart the machine!

Comment: The DNS setting does not modify `/etc/resolv.conf` in the VM.  That is tied up in VirtualBox networking.  It modifies the DNS server that the Docker daemon itself uses.

Comment: Set this config to `["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]`, restarted docker machine, restarted docker service, then restarted docker machine, then reprovisioned it, then restarted it again for good measure. The machine is inexplicably trying to use `10.0.2.3` as DNS server.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. I put the DNS server 8.8.8.8 there and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me too. I put the DNS server in `/etc/resolve.conf` file inside the machine!!! dns addresses inside `json.config` don't apply on virtual machine(`/etc/resolve.conf`)

Comment: anyone has solution to this? I recently ran into the same problem, and changing the Dns settings in config.json does not fix it.

Comment: The only that seems to work is to add line "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" ssh "${VM}" "sudo sed -i.bkp '/--label provider=virtualbox/a --dns 8.8.8.8\\\n--dns 8.8.4.4' /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart" after yes | "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" regenerate-certs "${VM}" in script start.sh that is run every time Docker Quickstart Terminal is started.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10 docker's gui give some facilities.

Just right click on docker's icon in the tray bar and select "Settings" item.

[image: Docker's options]

Then, on the Docker's window, select the "Network" section and change the DNS option from "Automatic" to "Fixed" and hit "Apply". Docker will restart itself after that. I putted the Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) and it worked fine to me.

[image: docker's network section with dns config]

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I change this option to fixed and set an ip then check the resolv.conf in the container... it's unchanged. I don't believe this works.