# How to change DNS with Docker Toolbox for Windows 10 Home version

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-toolbox

I have an issue with Docker Toolbox :

```
$ docker build -t myproject/myproject-docker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  371.8MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:37892->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
```

Someone suggests maybe a solution in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776535/5240905
by changing dns address to 8.8.8.8

But in order to do that I need to modify docker settings and I can't figure out where it is...
I have no docker icon in the system tray cause of Docker Toolbox (different from Docker for Windows).

[image]

So, does that error come from the dns address which is incorrect, and if it's the case : Where can I change the default profile of Docker to choose 8.8.8.8 as default DNS address ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this solution works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34301566/5240905

You just need to restart the VM.